# Converting Dictionary key values into NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I just successfully finished making my first JSON request and deserializing the information now all I need to do is know how to gather a few values from my dictionary. Here's what the request looks like:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Make the URL connection in order to download JSON/XML data.
    NSString *urlAsString = @"weburlgoeshere...";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // Error and success message handling.
    [NSURLConnection
    sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
    queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
         if([data length] > 0 &&
            error == nil){
             NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

             if (jsonData != nil){
                 NSError *error = nil;

                 NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                 if(error == nil)
                 NSLog(@"%@", [result valueForKey:@"merchants"]);
             }

         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 &&
         error == nil){
         NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded");

         }
         else if (error != nil){
         NSLog(@"Error happened = %@", error);

         }


     }];

}
```

This is what logs out to the console:

```
branches =         (
                        {
                city = "......";
                country = "United States";
                countryIsoCode = USA;
                distanceInKms = "8.31";
                distanceInMiles = "5.16";
                id = 7952205;
                latitude = ".......";
                longitude = "........";
                name = ".......";
                state = ......;
                stateIsoCode = .....;
                street = ".........";
                telephone = "";
            }
        );
        id = 174535;
        logoUrl = ".......";
        name = ".......";
```

So I stored all these values in an NSDictionary that I called **"result"** and I would like to know how to gather and store **SPECIFIC** key values for latitude and longitude in an NSNumber. I'm thinking that I might need to fastEnumerate most of these with a block, and then deal with the accordingly. The intent here is to use these values and display them onto a map. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can access Required values for your keys in this manner.

```
NSArray * array = [dic objectForKey:@"branches"];
NSDictionary *furtherNames = array[0];
NSNumber *latitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[furtherNames objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue]];
NSNumber *longitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[furtherNames objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]];
```

All you need to observe is that () => Array of objects, {} => Dictionary. Hence traverse them accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, I just realized that I could just create a @property in order to store the values in the dictionary. I think what's really strange is that one of those keys (latitude and longitude) are coming up when I call the following: [dic allKeys]. Maybe it's because they're nested? Any ideas?

Comment: +1, and you can use newer syntax result[@"branches"][0][@"latitude"].  @user2745444, you won't see nested keys if you log allKeys, so your dictionary (dic) must be pointing to one of the nested dictionaries.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was able to grab the exact value that I needed! Would I have to use a fastEnumeration block in order to create an array of all of these values individually? Thanks!